# how can i get comment text base on comment id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

how can i get comment text base on comment id?

I use facebook js api ,when comment create, I want to use ajax insert the comment content in my database, but the code bellow return no text content , how can i get contents?

in ajax, I will get contents base on the commentID , how to get content in FQL?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.Event.subscribe(
    'comment.create',
    function(href,commentID){
        // can only get commentID
        // I need to get comment content, how to do ?

        $.ajax({
            url:'jy_ajax.php',
            type:'POST',
            data:{
                commentID:commentID
            },
            success:function(){}
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try logging `href` to see what it contains. As far as I can remember the first argument would normally be `response`, containing the comment itself, not a href ?

Comment: href is only ther url you commented , no comment text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current user is connected to your application then this is pretty easy to do, if they are not then we have to do some guesswork. This is because the ID returned in the `comment.create` event is not a public comment id - it is a private one so only the creator can retrieve the comment message. I don't know why Facebook have done it this way.

```
FB.Event.subscribe(
  'comment.create',
  function(commentCreateResponse) {

    /* if the user is authed then you can do this */
    FB.api( '/' + commentCreateResponse.commentID, function(commentResponse) {
      console.log(commentResponse.message);
    });

    /* if not, then we have grab all the comments and guess */
    FB.api('/comments?ids='+commentCreateResponse.href, function(allCommentsResponse) {
      var comments = allCommentsResponse[commentCreateResponse.href].comments.data;
      var mostRecentComment = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < comments.length; i++) {
        var comment = comments[i];
        if ((false == mostRecentComment) || (comment.created_time > mostRecentComment.created_time)) {
          mostRecentComment = comment;
        }
      }
      console.log(mostRecentComment.message);
    });
  }
);
```

The above example shows both methods - you should remove the method which you don't need.

In the first method, for when the user is connected, it just hits the Graph API with the comment ID and returns the result.

In the second method, for when the user is not connected to our app, it queries all of the public available comments and looks for the most recent one and assumes that this is the one made by the user. This will only work in an environment where you do not have multiple users making comments at the same time - it will get the results wrong in that situation.

Hope that helps.